# Как принять класс на одной из сторон(web-server)?

Tags: java

Я передаю данные через сокет, и, т.к. мне надо передавать несколько переменных(так, наверно, правильнее), я на клиентской стороне создаю класс, содержащий эти поля, преобразую его в `byte[]` и передаю. Сервер данные принимает, но собрать обратно в класс, такой же, с теми же полями, сеттерами и геттерами, не получается. Говорит что `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.messagedna.dlp.data.Message`, причем `com.messagedna.dlp.data.Message` - это путь к классу на клиентской стороне. Единственное, чем эти классы (на серверной и на клиентской стороне) различаются, так это пакетами в которых лежат. Как мне собрать на серверной стороне мой класс?

Comment: сериализуй - десериализуй

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется, вы получите `ClassNotFoundException`, ведь, как вы сами сказали:

> Единственное, чем эти классы (на серверной и на клиентской стороне) различаются, так это **пакетами в которых лежат**

`Fully-qualified` имена классов должны совпадать.

Если всё же хочется держать их в разных пакетах, не используйте стандартную сериализацию, оборачивайте данные в некий обособленный формат: `xml/json/bson/protobuf/etc`.